# htaccess и вывод PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Как через `.htaccess` сделать так, чтобы при заходе на:

- `site.com/site` работал обработчик `site.php`
- `site.com/test` работал обработчик `test.php`
- `site.com/category/{dynamic-category-name}` работал обработчик `category.php`?

Comment: Вам уже не раз отвечали, молодой человек, я в том числе. Продублирую - прочтите про маршрутизацию и `MVC` и вы получите ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: Мне сложно понять то что написано в документации. Можете показать простейший пример?

Comment: Вам не нужно читать документацию(простите меня те кто тратит жизнь на описания документации), вам нужно просто прочесть https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwij-7PC39baAhXjZpoKHW3lCJwQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhabrahabr.ru%2Fpost%2F150267%2F&usg=AOvVaw0VgZ4RBHhNJI3K5gjsOIQq. И вы получите ответы на все вопросы, а потом уже, когда что-то не поймете, уточняйте здесь.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов при чем тут MVC вообще? у человека вопрос про htaccess. Если я спрашиваю про сложение натуральных чисел, то не надо меня отправлять гуглить учебник по мат.анализу.

Comment: Данный ресурс не приветствует вопросы в стиле "подумайте за меня". Где пример что вы пробовали, но оно не работает?

Comment: @teran да при-том, что он задаёт сие вопрос третий раз, и его задача мне объективно понятна. Ему нужен Роутинг, для создания виртуальных адресов. Во всех мануалах по MVC в полной мере описан роутинг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можете показать простейший пример?

Для первого правила простейшим сопоставлением будет выражение `site/?`, где `/?` обозначает необязательный слэш в конце строки. Чтобы написать сопоставление данного паттерна нужному вам обработчику, следует воспользоваться директивой [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Формат синтаксиса директивы, согласно документации, имеет следующий вид^

```
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
```

где `pattern` это ваш шаблон для сопоставления url, `substitution` это замена, т.е. куда этот запрос перенаправляется. Далее указываются флаги.
Чаще всего,  наверное, используются флаги `L` (остановить просмотр правил) и `QSA` (добавлять исходные параметры запроса).

отсюда следует, что простейшим примером для вашей первой URL будет

```
RewriteRule    ^site/?$     site.php    [L, QSA]
```

Очевидно, что для `test`, правило будет аналогичным. Также вы можете написать и общее правило для этих двух выражений, используя [группы и обратные ссылки](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

```
RewriteRule   ^(site|test)/?$   $1.php    [L,QSA]
```

Здесь в скобках обозначена группа захвата, внутри нее `|` обозначает `или`, а `$1` в замене обозначает ссылку на эту группу (на первую группу). Групп может быть несколько.

Для реализации последней ссылки вам тоже понадобятся группы, но теперь в группу будет попадать название категории.

```
RewriteRule    ^category/(.*)    category.php?cat=$1   [L,QSA]
```

тут `.`  обозначает любой символ, а `*` - ноль и более повторений.